# How to reverse legend (labels and color) so high value starts at bottom?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

whats the best way to invert the legend label order so the 7 is down and the 1 is upstairs?

[image: ggplot legend challenge]

```
df$day <- as.numeric(df3$day)
blues <- colorRampPalette(c('#132B43', '#56B1F7'))

p4 <- 
    ggplot(subset(df,feedback==1&stp>20), aes(x=correct, fill=day, colour=day)) +
    geom_histogram(colour="black", binwidth=10) +
    facet_grid(day ~ .) +
    ggtitle("Over-pronation histogram") +
    ylab("Count (150s period)") +
    xlab("% Steps in over-pronation") +guide_legend(reverse = false)
```

Comment: have you tried `guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)`?

Comment: tried that of course. no effect.

Comment: data set:https://www.dropbox.com/s/5vfjk5kpvfv1vqe/_logs9.csv code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b0ckwshfs3ipq57/_embspaper.R

Answer (score 59):

Your code is quite strange, with `false` instead of `FALSE` and incorrectly placed `guide_legend`. The correct usage is (@Harpal gives a hint on that):

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:4, y=4:1, col=factor(1:4)), aes(x=x, y=y, col=col)) + 
  geom_point(size=10)
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:4, y=4:1, col=factor(1:4)), aes(x=x, y=y, col=col)) + 
  geom_point(size=10) + guides(colour = guide_legend(reverse=T))
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 17):

If you're putting it in numeric and it's a continuous scale, you're better off with `scale_fill_continuous(trans = 'reverse')` or `scale_colour_continuous`.  Using your code, this would give:

```
ggplot(subset(df,feedback==1&stp>20), aes(x=correct, fill=day, colour=day)) +
    geom_histogram(colour="black", binwidth=10) +
    facet_grid(day ~ .) +
    ggtitle("Over-pronation histogram") +
    ylab("Count (150s period)") +
    xlab("% Steps in over-pronation")+
    scale_fill_continuous(trans = 'reverse')
```

Answer (score 8):

For continuous scales, `guide_colorbar` is required.

Here I reverse color **direction**. Then I reverse color and size **order** with different functions

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
iris %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  clean_names() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = sepal_length,
             y = petal_width,
             size = sepal_width,
             color = petal_length)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~species,scales = "free") +
  #reverse color direction (the higher in value, the darker in color)
  scale_color_continuous(trans = 'reverse') +
  #edit legends
  guides(
    #reverse color order (higher value on top)
    color = guide_colorbar(reverse = TRUE),
    #reverse size order (higher diameter on top) 
    size = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```