# Change order of filling variable on a ggplot geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a barplot which I changed the order of samples "BB" "AA". They are filled by condition location.

How can I change the order of the variable filling of the legend so the bars show as Washington-Mongolia-Egypt? (ie: the black column (Egypt) would be on the right, then Mongolia, then the white one (Washington) would be on the left).

```
sample <- c("AA", "AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "BB")
location<- c("Washington", "Mongolia", "Egypt", "Washington", "Mongolia", "Egypt" )
value <- c(0.03, 0.06, 0.02, 0.0051, 0.0082, 0.003)
data <- data.frame(sample, location, value)


ggplot(data, aes(fill=location, y=value, x=sample)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", color="black")+
theme_classic()+
 scale_fill_grey() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("BB", "AA"))
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reverse legend (labels and color) so high value starts downstairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458970/how-to-reverse-legend-labels-and-color-so-high-value-starts-downstairs)

Comment: @dc37 Thanks, but what that function does is reversing the legend labels, I would like to reverse the order of the columns so that Washington-Mongolia-Egypt changes the column order for each sample. SO the black column (Egypt) would be on the right. <- I am adding this to the original post to be more clear on the question.

Comment: Do you want the legend labels be reversed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position_dodge2` with the argument `reverse = TRUE` in `geom_col` (which is equivalent to `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`).

I also use `guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))` to reverse legend labeling and match the order of bars

```r
library(ggplot2) 

ggplot(data, aes(fill=location, y=value, x=sample)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE) color="black")+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_grey() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("BB", "AA"))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

---

**EDIT: Adding `geom_errobar` using `position_dodge2`**

As documented in this discussion (https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2251), when using `position_dodge2` fro `geom_col`, if you want to add `geom_errorbar`, you need to play with `padding` argument:

```r
sample <- c("AA", "AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "BB")
location<- c("Washington", "Mongolia", "Egypt", "Washington", "Mongolia", "Egypt" )
value <- c(0.03, 0.06, 0.02, 0.0051, 0.0082, 0.003)
sd <- c(0.003, 0.0012, 0.0015, 0.00025, 0.0002, 0.0001) 
data <- data.frame(sample, location, value, sd)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(fill=location, y=value, x=sample)) + 
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE), stat="identity", color="black")+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_grey() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("BB", "AA"))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = value-sd, ymax = value+sd), 
                position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE, padding = 0.6, width = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: If adding the error bars, they show in the original order, therefore not matching, could we reverse them too?
sd <- c(0.003, 0.0012, 0.0015, 0.00025, 0.0002, 0.0001)
data <- data.frame(sample, location, value, sd)

Comment: "ggplot(data, aes(fill=location, y=value, x=sample)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE), color="black")+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_grey() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("BB", "AA"))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))+
  geom_errorbar( aes(x=sample, ymin=value-sd, ymax=value+sd), width=0.2, colour="black", alpha=0.9, size=0.5, position=position_dodge(0.9))"

Comment: I tried that earlier and it does change the order, but plots them in the central column (not on each column), maybe changing width or some other feature?

Comment: Cheers, let me know! :)

Comment: I edited my answer. You have to play with `padding` argument in `position_dodge2` fro `geom_errorbar`.

Comment: Tricky one, but worked! thanks for the help @dc37 !!