# How to reverse legend (labels only) so high value starts at bottom?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Very similar to [How to reverse legend (labels and color) so high value starts at bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458970/how-to-reverse-legend-labels-and-color-so-high-value-starts-at-bottom) except keeping colours the same: I have a `ggmap` with raster values that to from 0 to 100. For various reasons, I want to change the legend values to show 100 to 0, without changing the colour scale on the legend, nor in the plot. I tried an example which shows the problem, using `scale_colour_viridis_c` instead of `scale_fill_viridis`:

```r
dplyr::tibble(x = runif(100),
              y = runif(100)) |> 
  ggplot2::ggplot() +
  ggplot2::geom_point(mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = x,
                                             y = y,
                                             colour = x)) + 
  ggplot2::scale_colour_viridis_c()
```

[image]

So if I try `trans = 'reverse'`:

```r
dplyr::tibble(x = runif(100),
              y = runif(100)) |> 
  ggplot2::ggplot() +
  ggplot2::geom_point(mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = x,
                                             y = y,
                                             colour = x)) + 
  ggplot2::scale_colour_viridis_c(
    labels = ggplot2::waiver(),
    trans = 'reverse'
  )
```

[image]

The added `trans` parameter reverses the legend values (yay) while maintaining the legend colours (yay) but reverses the plot values (boo).

In my code I'm using `viridis::scale_fill_viridis` not `scale_colour_viridis_c`, however in both cases, trying to address this with `guides` just makes the legend binned without changing any order:

```r
dplyr::tibble(x = runif(100),
              y = runif(100)) |> 
  ggplot2::ggplot() +
  ggplot2::geom_point(mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = x,
                                             y = y,
                                             colour = x)) + 
  ggplot2::scale_colour_viridis_c() +
  ggplot2::guides(colour = ggplot2::guide_legend(reverse = T))
```

[image]

I was hoping to simply modify the `labels` parameter mathematically by substitution:

```
labels = 100 - ggplot2::waiver(),
```

However it seems `waiver` isn't evaluated as a range of numbers until later (or something) because:

> Error in 100 - ggplot2::waiver() : non-numeric argument to binary operator

I wonder if there's a clever way to force `labels` to work? This plot exists within a function within a package, however the values should always be >0 to 100 (I remove 0 itself). I just tried copying the labels as seen on the plot:

```
labels = c("25", "50", "75", "100"),
```

But:

> Error in `get_labels()`:! `breaks` and `labels` are different lengths

Underlining that I fundamentally don't understand how `waiver` works in the background, or how to get at its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the labels as `c(75, 50, 25)` and for safety set the breaks as `c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)` so you know they are in the right place

```r
dplyr::tibble(x = runif(100),
              y = runif(100)) |> 
  ggplot2::ggplot() +
  ggplot2::geom_point(mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = x,
                                             y = y,
                                             colour = x)) + 
  ggplot2::scale_colour_viridis_c(breaks = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), 
                                  labels = c(75, 50, 25))
```

[image]

An alternative is to use a labeling lambda function if you want ggplot to choose the breaks:

```r
dplyr::tibble(x = runif(100),
              y = runif(100)) |> 
  ggplot2::ggplot() +
  ggplot2::geom_point(mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = x,
                                             y = y,
                                             colour = x)) + 
  ggplot2::scale_colour_viridis_c(labels = ~ 100 * (1 - .x))
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps just use `labels = rev`.

Comment: @lotus yes, that's a good idea, though I'm unsure if the OP wanted the numbers in a 0-100 scale or 0-1 scale; the question is ambiguous on this point. If it's the latter then your suggestion would be the simplest approach.

Comment: Thanks both. `labels = rev` works although it includes NA at the top, which wasn't there before - not sure why this would be. `labels = ~ 100 - .x` (tweak on Allan's suggestion) works a treat - Allan I'll accept yours as the answer. Thanks folks!